# How do center an image within another image and have it responsive to mobile landscape?

Tags: css, css-position, responsive

I have a play image which needs centering over another image. I'm using percentages, to try to have it working on all devices, but the percentages are not acting like they should. I have taken screenshots of the mobile site in portrait and landscape, you can find them here https://i.stack.imgur.com/LEqZZ.jpg

The desktop site has an entirely different row which is hidden on small devices, the code below is visible exclusively on the mobile site.

Here's the css:

```
.parent {
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
.image1 {
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}
.image2 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 30%;
  left: 43%;
  z-index: 2;
}
```

working, sort of. The HTML:

```
<div class="parent">
<img class="image1" src="https://placehold.it/1"/ alt="1">
<img class="image2" src="https://placehold.it/2"/ alt="2">
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made your .image1 class a block element, centered the image and using transform property brought image2 in the center

```css
.parent {
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
.image1 {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: block;
  z-index: 1;
}
.image2 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -moz-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="parent">
    <img class="image1" src="http://kingofwallpapers.com/image/image-025.jpg" alt="1" />
    <img class="image2" src="https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/material-audio-video/20/play-circle-outline-128.png" alt="2" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You’ve set `.image1` to be relative, but this won’t have an impact on `.image2` since it is not a child of `.image1`. Also it is unclear what sizes the images will have.

If the second image should always scale up and down with the first one, keeping it’s position, it could be done like so:

```
.parent {
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 960px; /* i. e. never exceed 960px in width = max-width of .image1 */
    position: relative;
}

.image1 {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
}

.image2 {
    left: 25%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 25%;
    width: 50%;
}
```

`.image2` would have a 25% distance of `.image1`’s height/width to top, left and right.

Answer (score 0):

Changed size of image to demonstrate properly

Gave width to parent div to absolute position

```css
.parent {
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 300px;
}
.image1 {
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}
.image2 {
  position: absolute;
   top: 32%;
   left: 32%;
   z-index: 2;
   border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  
 </head>
  <body>
    <div class="parent">
      <img class="image1" src="https://placehold.it/300x300"/ alt="1">
      <img class="image2" src="https://placehold.it/100x100"/ alt="2">
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I your first image dictate the size of the parent container, then you should position your images like this (for my code, I've use divs with fixed size. You could give your images display: block)

```css
.parent {
  position: relative;
  border: 2px solid gray;
}

.child-1 {
  height:300px;
  width: 300px;
  background: lightgreen;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.child-2 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  background: salmon;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child-1"></div>
  <div class="child-2"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

About responsiveness, use 'media query'

set width for image 2, for example, 50%

now set left: 25%